# How can I add external jQuery to Magento <head /> via the CMS?

Tags: xml, magento, content-management-system

On a Magento installation, I'm trying to insert xml into the Layout Update XML of my home page. I already have some xml in there that is working, but I would like to add a jQuery script to run my slideshow. I had it in page.xml (and was planning to move it to my local.xml at some point), where it was working, but it broke the Add to cart on product pages. So, I thought I would consolidate onto just the main page, and put it into the Layout Update XML. For some reason it isn't coming through.

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.7.1.noConflict.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>folder/slider.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

Any ideas why it would work in my page.xml and not in here?

Here is the nesting idea in page.xml

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Where do you have these js files placed? 
With homepage, do you mean CMS page Homepage? Did you placed it in textarea originally containing commented code <!--<reference name="content"> ... etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as follows :

add javascript into local.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js</script></action>
      <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/carouFredSel.js</script></action>
   </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

then make a custom home page template ( take reference from 1column.phtml ), select this template for homepage from CMS.

Put the following content in home page "XML Layout Update" section from Design tab.
Here is mine setting which I remove whole prototype scripts from homepage is because didn't want.

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/builder.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/effects.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/controls.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>scriptaculous/slider.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ccard.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/menu.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/js.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/translate.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>varien/form.js</name><params/></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/prototype.formalize.min.js</script></action>
<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/formalize.css</name><params/></action>
```

Also, don't create a specific noConflict page, just put end of the jQuery script which is working well.

For instance, here is mine :

`jQuery&&define("jquery",[],function(){return f})})(window);var $jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();`

Also, yu should create `jquery` folder in root `js` directory, not in skin folder `js` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Very helpful. Your code suggestion for local.xml worked, but I couldn't figure out how to just apply it to the home page. When it loads into product pages the add to cart button doesn't work (there may be other things in checkout that break). This is what I use to reference the two external jquery scripts in my local.xml `<reference name="head" template="page/home.phtml">` but it applies to all pages.

Comment: Oops sorry. Here is all of it. `<block template="page/home.phtml">
   <reference name="head" template="page/home.phtml">
    <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js</script></action>
    <action method="addJs"><script>folder/slider.js</script></action>
   </reference>
 </block>`

Comment: therefore, forget about local.xml, just put jquery scripts into homepage from CMS like `action method="addItem"` but don't remove special homepage layout `home.phtml`.

Comment: also, don't forget, there is a difference between `<type>js</type>` and `<type>skin_js</type>`. `skin_js` is skin folder javascript directory, other one root directories javascript directory.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your time! I still can't get it to load. Here is the code I have in the Layout Update XML: `<reference>
<reference name="head">
 <action method="addJs">
  <script>jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js</script>
 </action>
 <action method="addJs">
  <script>folder/slider.js</script>
 </action>
</reference>

<reference name="footer">
 <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_suppliers">
  <action method="setBlockId">
   <block_id>footer_suppliers</block_id>
  </action>
 </block>
</reference>
</reference>`. It seems that even if it can't get the correct .js file that it would build the link

Comment: you did a mistake, should be `<reference name="head"><action method="addItem"><type>js</type><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action></reference>`

Comment: This doesn't work either. `<reference name="head">
 <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><script>jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js</script></action>
 <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><script>folder/slider.js</script></action>
</reference>`. I'm not sure what is going on here. I've validated it. I just checked the path, and it is (from the root) /js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js and /js/folder/slider.js

Comment: it's being run with MAMP on my computer.

Comment: Oh no! I don't have 20 reputation - I'm new here.

Comment: I found several errors in my code that were causing other really strange issues. Because this is my first Magento project, I'm not familiar with some things, likely causing me to code an error. Either way, I ended up reinstalling Magento, and things have worked as expected thus far. Including being able to have my jquery (and remove the other scripts) only on the main page just as you described - your answer proved relavant and very helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: I waited you last night but I am happy to hear good news from you. Your welcome

Comment: Yes. I am VERY sorry. I tried opening connectnow and waiting for awhile, but then I had to leave. Thank you for waiting!